# SSRS limit number of rows returned for each column on report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I currently have a report which is set up to print name tags, I have created already 2 columns for the report and have a table within a list to group each person however at the moment when displaying as PDF it displays loads of names on page.

What I now need is that when display in PDF or Word, I need to limit the numbers of names returned in each of the columns to only 4 rows in each column giving a total of 8 names in the whole page.

Is this possible and how to achieve?

Similar to the below format:

```
Record 1    Record 5

Record 2    Record 6

Record 3    Record 7

Record 4    Record 8
```

Comment: If this is a one time job, you can just paste the results in to Excel, and then use the mail / label merge feature in Word to create your labels. Word has matching predefined layouts for most labels.

Comment: ideally trying to avoid extra clicks as i would want them to export from dynamics crm and printing with pdf

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar before.

You can set the **Row Grouping** to

```
=INT((CountRows() - 1) / 4) + 1
```

This will set the first four name tags to line 1, the next 4 to line 2 and so on.

Then set **Column Grouping** to use the remainder (MOD) of the Row Number (CountRow)

```
=CountRows() MOD 4
```

This will set Member tag 1 to column 1, 2 to column 2 and so on.

Of course I can't find the report that has this right now - I don't remember if there was an issue using CountRows and I had to use ROW_NUMBER in the query.

Comment: I'm currently only using a one row table, will this work that ?

Comment: Yes - the table would just have one cell (in Design view) which would stretch to 4 wide and however many rows needed.

Comment: CountRows won't change per row.  I expect that all of the rows would end up with the same exact value.  Use Row Number instead.